# Why is there a `%` appended to my command output

Tags: terminal, shell

See the following command output, there is a `%` appended to what I really want:

```
➜ ls *.md | tr '\n' ':'
README.md:%
```

What is the cause and how to eliminate it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're using `zsh` as your shell? It's an indicator that program's output didn't end with a newline. It's printed by `zsh`, not the program. The program works fine.

It's assumed that each program prints a newline at the end of its output. This allows the next program to safely start printing the next line - like for example the prompt, in case of shells. Here's an example with `bash`:

```
gronostaj:~# echo test
test
gronostaj:~#
```

`echo` will, by default, add a newline at the end. You can suppress this with `-n` and here's the result, again in `bash`:

```
gronostaj:~# echo -n test
testgronostaj:~#
```

That's not very cool. The assumption about output ending with a newline wasn't right and the prompt is concatenated at the end of previous output.

In `zsh`, the 2nd example would look like this:

```
➜ echo -n test
test%
➜
```

`zsh` prints the `%` character to indicate that a lack of newline was detected and it has appended it for you to avoid breaking the prompt. It's not the echo printing it, but the shell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation!